# Switch to fullscreen application switches to Desktop instead of app (after testing then disabling Stage Manager)

Tags: display, spaces, mission-control, fullscreen

I have reviewed all related questions that I found and have not found any that seem to address my specific problem, and I believe I have tested all permutations of the various configurations. My application switching seems completely broken.

---

I tested out Stage Manager today out of curiosity, but generally, I use nearly all my applications in fullscreen mode where they are each given their own workspace. I switch between them using Spotlight or shortcuts created with [Apptivate](http://www.apptivateapp.com/). After disabling Stage Manager to go back to my normal workflow, application switching does not behave normally.

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works correctly.
- Spotlight switches to the Desktop space and gives the correct menu bar.

  - Repeating this just stays on the Desktop.
  - I must <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or click the icon in the dock to get to the app.
  - This used to take me to the app. Why would I want to go to the desktop?
- While on the Desktop, if I click the icon:
  The first click loads the apps menu bar but does not switch to the window.
  The second click switches to the app's window.

Any ideas about what is going on? I currently have:

- *Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use* (off)
- *When switching to an application, switch to a Space with open windows for this application* (on)
- *Group windows by application* (off)
- *Displays have separate Spaces* (on)

But I have tried these in varying combinations.